# Falta de espaçamento nos elemento lista dentro de outra lista afeta o layout

Tags: suporte, bug, status-pronto, formatação, markdown

Não é um pergunta sobre html e css, é um problema no site e no meta mesmo.

Não sei se afeta os demais sites da rede, mas no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ tenho notado o seguinte problema, os elementos `<p>` tem margem em baixo o que facilita a leitura e a divisão dos parágrafos, no entanto os elementos de lista tem sua margem removida pelo all.css:

```
ol ul, ul ol, ul ul, ol ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Isto causa uma estranheza no texto que deveria ser separado, veja assim funciona como esperado:

> olá mundo
>
> - Foo
> - Bar
> - Baz
>
> Linha final

Já desta maneira a "item final" fica grudada a lista:

> olá mundo
>
> - Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla
> - Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla
> - Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla
>
>   1. Foo
>   2. Baz
>
>   Item final
>
> Linha final

Como esta a marcação:

```
olá mundo

- Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla
- Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla
- Bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla

  1. Foo
  1. Baz

  Item final

Linha final
```

Comment: O problema foi resolvido em algum momento desde a publicação dessa postagem, por isso estou considerando como status-pronto.