# Markdown, como inserir uma linha em branco após lista indentada?

Tags: suporte, formatação

Como posso inserir uma linha em branco entre "Texto indentado após linha em branco" e a **Lista 2 indentada**?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Mauris venenatis volutpat quam id auctor.

**Lista 1**

- *Linha 1*
- *Linha 2*

  **Lista 2 indentada**

  - *linha 1 da lista indentada*
  - *linha 2 da lista indentada*

  "Texto indentado após linha em branco".

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Mauris venenatis volutpat quam id auctor.

Comment: Eu acho que já perguntaram isso

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Falta de espaçamento nos elemento lista dentro de outra lista afeta o layout](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4731/falta-de-espa%c3%a7amento-nos-elemento-lista-dentro-de-outra-lista-afeta-o-layout)

Comment: Talvez o jeito seja colocar vários `&nbsp;` antes de "Texto indentado..."